# запуск скриптов php и js по кнопке

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, веб-программирование

Имеется кнопка, при нажатии на которую происходит php скрипт, на добавление данных в базу данных. Так же по этой кнопке вызывается js скрипт, со всплывающим окном окном, которое уведомляет об успешном добавлении данных в БД. Добавление и js работают. Но только при нажатии на кнопку js-скрипт срабатывает, но так как имеется еще и php скрипт, страница перезагружается и пользователь не видит всплывающее окно. Вопрос как настроить, чтобы  добавлялись данные и скрипт срабатывал?

```
<?php
                    include_once("bd.php");
                    if(isset($_POST['reg']))
                    {   
                        $stage = $_POST['stage'];
                        $team = strip_tags(trim($_POST['team']));
                        $fio_mem1 = strip_tags(trim($_POST['fio_mem1']));
                        $fio_mem2 = strip_tags(trim($_POST['fio_mem2']));
                        $fio_mem3 = strip_tags(trim($_POST['fio_mem3']));
                        $city = strip_tags(trim($_POST['city']));
                        $institution = strip_tags(trim($_POST['institution']));
                        $klass = strip_tags(trim($_POST['klass']));
                        $tel = strip_tags(trim($_POST['tel']));
                        $mail = strip_tags(trim($_POST['mail']));
                        $head = strip_tags(trim($_POST['head']));
                        $position = strip_tags(trim($_POST['position']));

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO members (stage, team, fio_mem1, fio_mem2, fio_mem3, city, institution, klass, tel, mail, head, position)
                            VALUES('$stage','$team','$fio_mem1','$fio_mem2','$fio_mem3','$city','$institution','$klass','$tel','$mail','$head','$position')";
                        if($link->query($sql)===TRUE) {
                            echo "";
                        }  
                    }
                    ?>
```

```js
<script>
                    $(window).on("load", function(){
                        $('#button1').click(function(){
                            $('#myModal').fadeIn(500);
                        })

                        $('#close').click(function(){
                            $('#myModal').fadeOut(500);
                        })
                        $(document).click(function(event){
                            if ($(event.target).closest('#button1').length || $(event.target).closest('#button1').length) return;
                            $('#myModal').fadeOut(500);
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        });
                    })
                </script>
```

```css
.modal {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: bold;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(18, 30, 119, 0.8);
    
}

#modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    
    
}

#close {
    color: #aaa; 
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<div class="container">
            <div class="forma2 clearfix">
                <form method="post" action="reg.php">
                    <div class="main_reg">
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="stage">Вид этапа</label>
                            <select name="stage" id="stage">
                                <option value="" disabled>Выберите этап</option>
                                <option value="Очный">Очный</option>
                                <option value="Заочный">Заочный</option>    
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="team">Название команды</label>
                            <input type="text" id="team" name="team" placeholder="Название команды">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="fio_mem1">ФИО  первого участника</label>
                            <input type="text" id="fio_mem1" name="fio_mem1" placeholder="ФИО">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="fio_mem2">ФИО  второго участника</label>
                            <input type="text" id="fio_mem2" name="fio_mem2" placeholder="ФИО">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="fio_mem3">ФИО  третьего участника</label>
                            <input type="text" id="fio_mem3" name="fio_mem3" placeholder="ФИО">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="city">Ваш город</label>
                            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Город">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="institution">Учебное учреждение</label>
                            <input type="text" id="institution" name="institution" placeholder="Учебное заведение">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="klass">Класс\специальнсть</label>
                            <input type="text" id="klass" name="klass" placeholder="Класс\специальность">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="tel">Номер тел. руководителя</label>
                            <input type="text" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Телефон">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="mail">e-mail руководителя</label>
                            <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="e-mail">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="head">ФИО руководителя</label>
                            <input type="text" id="head" name="head" placeholder="ФИО">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="position">Должность руководителя</label>
                            <input type="text" id="position" name="position" placeholder="Должность">
                        </div>
                        <div class="button_reg">
                            <button id="button1" class="button1" value="Зарегистрировать" type="submit" name="reg" OnClick='function()'>Зарегистрировать</button>
                            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                                <div id="modal-content">
                                    <span id="close">&times;</span>
                                    <p>Вы успешно прошли регистрацию!</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Одно слово: `ajax`.

Comment: _«Имеется кнопка, при нажатии на которую происходит php скрипт»_ (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Ну да я читал про ajax, просто подумал можно другим способом как-то это реализовать, но видимо нет, поэтому спасибо

Comment: @Qwerty, можно и без аякса: кнопке отправки в форме `type="button"`, и в обработчике клика по ней (после выполнения нужного тебе кода) вызывать метод `submit()` формы, для ее отправки.

Comment: Еще можно прослушивать *событие* `submit` на форме, сразу вызывая `preventDefault()` и затем после твоего кода метод `submit()`. Насколько помню, вызов этого метода формы **не** диспатчит одноименное событие, в отличие от отправки пользователем (но это лучше проверить заранее, могу ошибаться).

Comment: хорошо, щас попробую разобраться в этом